# Error seeding database in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am currently using Phoenix 1.0 and attempting to seed my database. The link below is to my seed file.

https://gist.github.com/dprice809/72463b6c8ec8b81fe9a5

After running the seed file I get this

```
** (TokenMissingError) priv/repo/seeds.exs:73: missing terminator: " (for string starting at line 67)
(elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:68: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:55: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
(elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

I will add the troublesome code when I determine what is.

Comment: You are missing a closing `"` after Super Nintendo on line 45. Why are you using `case Repo.insert!`? You do not need the `case` since `insert!` will raise an error upon failure. Also the last line you have a typo: it should be `Repo` not `Repon` (plus you are not inserting anything)

Comment: I'm coming from .Net so I am still learning the syntax.